# How to create a line that conect two images in responsive website?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]
Anyone knows how this can be acomplished?

The website is using bootstrap 4 and the lines must be able to disapear in extra small screens.

Comment: I think the best bet is svg to make the line (if it's only vertical / horizontal, just the gif) and then play with css/javascript to make it appear in the right position and with the right dimension. I was required something like that one month ago, but I managed to convince my customer to use an existing JS library for Gantt diagrams, which did not have lines, but colors, to distinguish distinct flows, so we didn't have to waste time in implementing something for which HTML has not been designed.

Comment: borders of divs? put solid borders top left and vice versa. around the text field and right next one to the image upwards and repeat it

Comment: That's whitty... yep, I like more borders than gifs/svgs.

Answer (score 3):

This should help....

http://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/xEOAOm

Replace the `div.circle` with your image..

Answer (score 2):

If the final result will be like your sketch, you can try to think these lines as borders of simple div, and the CSS will be something like

```
.div-top{
  width: 100% /*resize this to adapt it*/
  height: 20px; /*give correct value*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; /*for example*/
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*for example*/
}
.div-bottom{
  width: 100% /*resize this to adapt it*/
  height: 20px; /*give correct value*/
  border-right: 1px solid black; /*for example*/
}
```

You can follow these examples and build all the lines you need. The HTML code must be like this

```
<div class="div-top"></div>
<div class="div-bottom"></div>
```

Comment: I can't do it like this because the image and the text are in different columns and if the text height is bigger than the image the borders are pushed down.

Comment: And what if you put these colums inside a row  and then make another row for the div with borders ?

Comment: this is what I explained before, good one. and I really would appreciate a svg solution if anyone got the time cause this does interest me also.